# Sphinx: button inside literalinclude blocks

Tags: python, html, python-sphinx

I have a desktop application and a user guide written in Sphinx. The API is explained with the use of code blocks that are imported with `literalinclude` blocks.

What I would like to have is a button inside or close to each code block. The button is intended for opening the respective example in our application.

What I have achieved so far (see below) is a button *above the code block*, that I have to include manually every time I use a `literalinclude` statement.

**How can I put the button *inside* the code block rather than above?**

A particularly beautiful result would be a transparent button like [Chris Holdgraf's Sphinx copybutton](https://sphinx-copybutton.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). But at the moment I would already be happy to have the button as it is located in the top right corner of the code block.

---

**Minimal example of how things are right now**

[image: screenshot of result]

The button is rendered above the code block. But I want to have it inside (at the top right corner).

Folder structure:

```
conf.py
index.rst
source_file.py
load_source.py
```

Content of index.rst:

```
:load_example:`source_file.py`  

.. literalinclude:: source_file.py
```

Content of source_file.py:

```py
import numpy as np

print "hello extension"

for i in range(3):   
   print np.sin(i)
```

Content of load_souce.py extension file:

```py
from docutils import nodes

# HTML code to generate button
button_raw = """
<script>
function openScriptFunction() {
   callBackHandler.openScript("%s");
}
</script>

<button onclick="openScriptFunction()">Load %s</button>
"""

def setup(app):
    app.add_role('load_example', load_example_script)

def load_example_script(name, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner, options={}, content=[]):
    node = nodes.raw(rawsource = button_raw%(text, text), text = button_raw%(text, text), format="html")
    return [node], []
```

This extension is included in the conf.py by `extensions = ['load_source']`

---

Comment: I would suggest that you accomplish this through custom CSS or JavaScript. It might be possible through Sphinx, but I would think it would be extremely difficult in comparison.

Comment: @StevePiercy thanks for the help. That's also how it is done in the copybutton project. I guess, that's my chance to finally learn some CSS and JavaScript, then ...